# iOS UI Test: How to get a list of element

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm testing on iOS with XCUITest, in a search test case, I'd like to verify that all search suggestions begins with the letter a user enter, say if I enter "p", search suggestion should have "ps4", "phone", "ps3" etc.

By looking around I feel like most element query methods will try to return a single element,
eg:
     `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH[cd] 'p'")`
     `app.buttons.elementMatchingPredicate(predicate)`

while in some cases, a list of elements matching the same condition can also be important, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I think this should be a unit test rather than a UI test. You're testing functionality here (search the letter "p" and get a list back). The UI test should just confirm that a label (or list) is displayed after clicking the "search" button. It shouldn't be too concerned with its contents.

Comment: @Hodson I kind of agree with you, I always struggle on how much detail should UI test verify

Answer (score 1):

@nieschumi first of all looks like this task is not for ui.
so, why can't u use one of functions:

```
 /*! Returns a new query that applies the specified attributes or predicate to the receiver. The predicate will be evaluated against objects of type id<XCUIElementAttributes>. */
open func matching(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> XCUIElementQuery

open func matching(_ elementType: XCUIElementType, identifier: String?) -> XCUIElementQuery

open func matching(identifier: String) -> XCUIElementQuery


/*! Returns a new query for finding elements that contain a descendant matching the specification. The predicate will be evaluated against objects of type id<XCUIElementAttributes>. */
open func containing(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> XCUIElementQuery

open func containing(_ elementType: XCUIElementType, identifier: String?) -> XCUIElementQuery
```

? And than check count of query if u need

Example:

```
 app.buttons.matching(NSPredicate(format: "label == [cd] %@", myVar)).count>1 ? doSmthWithQuery(): doSmthWithElement()
```